# List of holidays for Île-de-France weekend/holiday pass?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, paris, public-holidays

The Île-de-France [ticket jeunes week-end](http://vianavigo.com/fr/titres-et-tarifs/les-tickets-et-forfaits-journalier/le-ticket-jeunes-week-end/) is valid on Saturdays, Sundays, and other holidays. Where can one get a list of dates on which this ticket will be valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of French legal holidays can be found [on a French government website](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/F2405.xhtml) (in French) or simply [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_holidays_by_country#France). They are:

- January 1
- [Easter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter) Monday, April 9, in 2012
- May 1
- May 8
- [Ascension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_the_Ascension), May 17, in 2012
- [Whit Monday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whit_Monday), May 28, in 2012
- July 14
- August 15
- November 1
- November 11
- December 25

Comment: Thanks. Are these the holidays implemented by STIF (/RATP/SNCF/etc)?

Comment: These are the "jours fériés" or "fêtes légales" as defined by french laws. STIF conforms to them, as everybody else in France.